# Proper way to include_once for a php library being used in multiple php files (ie Twig)

Tags: php, twig

I am brand new to php, but have done some web development using other tools like asp.net mvc and django. I am trying to achieve a similar templating system that allows me to extend a base template, while providing some easier syntax in the templates while accessing data as well as maintaining an mvc oriented application, which seems very easy to break in php if you're not being careful!

I have come across Twig in my travels and it seems exactly what I need. Lightweight, and has almost identical syntax to django in templates (I imagine django was a concept derive from Twig).

So anyways, I'm trying to find a way to include the autoload information necessary for Twig to operate ie:

```
include_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('./templates');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => './tmp/cache',));
```

In just one place. Now, maybe I'm a silly goose and just adding this somewhere on the server lets the server figure it out? Ideally, the user would enter the site via my_domain/index.php *every* time and I could just include it there and be certain that it was included for interactions thereafter.

But some people have their favorite pages that they jump to, or for whatever reason they don't come to the site through my_domain/index.php. What would be the behavior if the above include information was in index.php, but the user jumped to another page that required it like login.php?

Big big big php scrub, so any help you can offer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't the Composer autoload mean you don't need to manually load the other packages?

Comment: Thanks for your response! Maybe! I'm not sure how composer works, and I did install via composer. I know the json is there with the "require" "twig//twig": "~1.0". So this may very well be the case! I have just trying to struggle along with the tutorials I can find and I'm not sure of phps infrastructure. (Or web servers, lets be honest)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I tried removing the includes and it threw an exception that Twig_Loader_Filesystem was not found, so I believe it does need to be included, though if there is another way to do this I'm interested in learning it.

Comment: @Aserian you should only remove the last include. You still need to include `vendor/autoload.php`, as that is the autoloader.

Comment: @Thomas thanks thomas! Does that mean I still have to include all the extra stuff in *every* php file that uses templating? (which is all of them)

Comment: @Aserian usually you only require the autoloader once in OOP. Since you are using composer, you should use the [composer autoload PSR-4 directive](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4). Here you specify your file structure, so composer also autoloads your own files.